# IPTABLES > MAC Filtering

Tags: networking, mac, firewall, iptables

I am newbie.
I tried DHCP Mac filtering is not enough to secure our networks and I think iptables will...
This is my concept:
I set a new laboratory (LAB) network.
My other network is connected to a LAB server running Ubuntu 12.04 Linux as a router. 
And my LAB server is connected to the switch for LAN PCs.
here is the image:

[image: My LAB Network]

What I want is:

1. I only want registered mac addresses to be able to have an internet/network connection.
2. I want those registered mac addresses connected only to the a specific network address for file sharing.

   - I want to know what are the steps should I follow.
     Do I have to:
     Flush all the iptables rules first then set default policies to DROP or set default policies after mac filtering.

I did some research related to these.

- [Link1](http://www.linuxpakistan.net/forum/viewtopic.php?p=35095%22%5Dhttp://www.linuxpakistan.net/forum/viewtopic.php?p=35095)
- [Link2](http://www.unix.com/security/160564-configure-iptables-allows-list-mac-address.html%22%5Dhttp://www.unix.com/security/160564-configure-iptables-allows-list-mac-address.html)
- [Link3](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/iptables-mac-filtering-601505/%22%5Dhttps://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/iptables-mac-filtering-601505)

--Flushing All IPTABLES Rules (all connections lost)

```
iptables -F        
iptables -X        
iptables -t nat -F        
iptables -t nat -X
```

--Setting Default Policies To DROP (same)

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP        
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP        
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

--MAC Address Filtering (the rule save but still doesn't work)
*list of mac addresses save to a mac_addresses_file*

```
cat mac_addresses_file | while read macfile        
do        
iptables -A FORWARD -m mac --mac-source $macfile -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT        
iptables -I INPUT -m mac --mac-source $macfile -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Then Set default policies to DROP

---

I am hoping for your help and we will work it out, guys.
Thanks

Comment: Here are some of the links.        [link2](http://www.unix.com/security/160564-configure-iptables-allows-list-mac-address.html"]http://www.unix.com/security/160564-configure-iptables-allows-list-mac-address.html)          
[link3](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/iptables-mac-filtering-601505/"]https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/iptables-mac-filtering-601505)

Comment: This question isn't really Ubuntu specific, this question might be more relevant for ServerFault or similar.